# How can I declare a parameter is a Stored Proc and C# to be both an IN and OUT?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

My code is like this:

Stored Proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
    @StatusId  INT OUTPUT,
```

C# code:

```
var sql = @"do.test @StatusId OUT,

SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[] {
   new SqlParameter("@StatusId",  SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output },
```

I know I can change this to be an OUTPUT by adding the word OUTPUT but how can I change it to be both an input and output in the stored procedure and in C#? Also give the code above, how could I set the status to be 99 or any other value?

Comment: `@StatusId  INT OUT`

Comment: All parameters are always `IN`. Even if they're marked as `OUTPUT` you can still assign them an initial value.

Comment: Thanks but how could I give the parameter a value when setting up a new SqlParameter ? The second parameter there is the datatype and sets a direction.  Where or how can I assign a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new SqlParameter("@StatusId",  SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output, Value = 99 }
```